# Update Angular 2 code take so long

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My development productivity falls since it takes almost 8 seconds to update the browser page. Slowness when angular-cli is recompiling app after update html or ts code. - [WDS] App updated. Recompiling... - Is there some solution to make it faster?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Hot Module Replacement https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-hmr it'll recompile only changed files, not all files. The best place to go with hmr - this sample seed app https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-seed or more complex seed app https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: I have tested both. They are very promissor. I found [this one too](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack) that is witch I have chosen.